# Unity+Firebase hangs from user.TokenAsync

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Below is my main login block in unity for firebase. It works fine when i get rid of:
 Debug.Log(user.TokenAsync(false).Result);
However due to security i MUST have a way to handle the session. Firebase even recommends this is the way you do it. No matter what you do though false OR true the application hangs and never continues. Am i using the tokenasync incorrectly?
I have also tried using whats commented out:
//StatusText.text = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.TokenAsync(true).Result;
but the currentuser returns null for some reason

```
FirebaseUser InvalidVerificationUser;
public void OnLoginButtonPressed()
{
    LoginButton.interactable = false;
    StatusText.text = "Logging in, please wait...";
    FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email.text, Password.text).ContinueWith((obj) =>
    {
        if (obj.IsFaulted || obj.IsCanceled)
        {
            StatusText.text = obj.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].ToString().Substring(28);
            LoginButton.interactable = true;
            return;
        }
        else if (!obj.Result.IsEmailVerified)
        {
            StatusText.text = "You must verify your email before logging in";
            ResendObject.SetActive(true);
            InvalidVerificationUser = obj.Result;
            LoginButton.interactable = true;
            return;
        }

        FirebaseUser user = obj.Result;
        if (user.DisplayName == "")
        {
            StatusText.text = "CRITICAL: No Username Found!";
        }
        else
            StatusText.text = "Hello: " + user.DisplayName;
        LoginButton.interactable = true;
        Debug.Log(user.TokenAsync(false).Result);
    });
    //StatusText.text = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser.TokenAsync(true).Result;
}
```

Comment: You forgot `{ }` for the `else` statement. Note that the `StatusText.text = "Hello: " + user.DisplayName` will execute when it is `else` **but** `LoginButton.interactable = true` and `Debug.Log(user.TokenAsync(false).Result)` will always execute. Are you sure that's what you want? I suspect null issues there

Comment: actually i did not forget { } because i don't want the other 2 lines to work only in the else. However i know it is not a null issue because when i have it succeed it still hangs

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with `SignInAnonymouslyAsync` hanging the Unity client and I got around it by awaiting both `SignInAnonymouslyAsync` and `TokenAsync`.

Something like this might help you:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await AuthDefaultInstance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email.text, Password.text);

if (!firebaseUser.IsEmailVerified)
{
    // do stuff here
}
else if (firebaseUser.DisplayName == string.Empty)
{
    // do stuff here
}
else
{
    string token = await firebaseUser.TokenAsync(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is `TokenAsync` is API that return `Task`

And so, everyone, don't ever use `.Result` of the `Task` object directly, this is common practice. Any task not just firebase api. Especially in unity. It has tendency to freeze the application with deadlock

Use `async/await` or `task.ContinueWith(callBack)` instead